# Improper integral $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x}{\sin x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Find out whether or not the following integral exists
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x}{\sin x} dx.$$

I'm pretty sure this integral doesn't exist but I can't seem to find a good way to prove this. It certainly seems way too hard to find the indefinite integral. Can someone please share a hint?

Comment: what happens to the integrand when $x\rightarrow \pi$? The indefinite integral can be expressed in terms of dilogarithms after the substitution $t=e^{ix}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two problems to treat: on $0$ and on $\pi$.

- On $0$ the function is extended since $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\sin x}$ exists so the integral
  $$\int_0^{\frac12}\frac{x}{\sin x}dx$$
  exists
- On $\pi$ and by the change of variable $t=\pi-x$ we find
  $$\int_{\frac12}^\pi\frac{x}{\sin x}dx=\int_0^{\pi-\frac12}\frac{\pi-t}{\sin t}dt$$
  and this integral isn't convergent since
  $$\frac{\pi-t}{\sin t}\sim_0\underbrace{\frac{\pi}{t}}_{\text{this term gives a divergent integral}}-1$$
  **Conclusion:** The given integral is divergent.

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int_{0}^{\pi}+\frac{x}{\sin%28x%29}+dx), the integral converges to $117.281$.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey this only shows that Wolfram Alpha sucks.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey it's interesting that Wolfram-Alpha says that, Mathematica says that it diverges

Comment: Can you please explain the last step with the $\sim_0$ ?

Comment: We use the Taylor series to get that $\sin t$ is asymptotically equivalent to $t$.@rehband

Comment: Got it, that's amazing!